# AWS Route53 routing wordpress subdirectories to different EC2 instances

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I have domain setup like `http://www.example.com/in` which is a wordpress multisite setup and hosted on a AWS EC2 instance.
I have to make another similar setup with url `http://www.example.com/uk` but on another EC2 instance.

The domain `www.example.com` is routed to only one IP of first instance.

Can anyone advise on how I should setup this routing to make this scenario on Amazon Route 53?

Comment: I am new to route53, and the domain is currently live and I don't want to try untested methods. If anyone already done this before will be much helpful to avoid any downtime on site.

Comment: DNS only allows for routing via hostnames. If you want to that, you need to use a proxy of some kind.

Comment: Has anyone tried setting this up correctly on AWS Route53, any reference will be much helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are serving your site using `apache` you can add a `.htaccess` rule on the instance hosting www.example.com to redirect www.example.com/uk traffic to another `ip` address.

This will mean you rely on `www.example.com` to redirect traffic for `www.example.com/uk`. In the event the instance running `www.example.com` were to become unavailable, `www.example.com/uk` would become inaccessible.

Alternatively, you can setup a `subdomain` in `Route53` with the following entry

`uk.example.com` `1.2.3.4`

This will mean that www.example.com/uk will need to be accessed using `uk.example.com` not `www.example.com/uk`

Comment: Thanks for the information. Server is using apache and wordpress. I don't want to use sub-domain. Site needs to be in sub-directory only. Can this be done using Route53 only, so that traffic for 2nd site will go to 2nd instance directly from Route53.

Comment: No, like all other DNS providers `Route53` allows the routing of hostnames (including subdomains) only.

Comment: So only option left is route via .htaccess then, right?

Comment: That is correct. The limitation of this would be; access to `www.example.com/uk`becomes dependent on the instance running `www.example.com`. So if the latter were to die, access to `www.example.com/uk` via this specific address would stop.